# How do we convert field values to a numeric type in the Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a CharField on my model, and I want to retrieve only the numbers in that CharField.

For example:

```
DEMO
025-SP
026
028
```

I want to retrieve these elements:

```
025-SP
026
028
```

And ultimately get the maximum value of the numbers in the strings:

```
>  Max(025, 026, 028) = 028
```

The padding zeroes are not necessary if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter using a regular expression. For example:

```
Model.objects.filter(value__regex=r'^\d+')
```

Comment: `r'^\d+$'`. `025-SP` shouldn't be in the result.

Comment: @sltn, actually, I didn't write my question correctly.  I would like `025-SP` to be in the result.